# Override enum toString() in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

How to customize toString() method for enum in Kotlin?

```
enum class GuideType(type: String) {
    DEF_TYPE("default"),

    override fun toString(): String {
        return type // not working!
    }
}
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Default constructor params need to be either `var` or `val` to be accessible outside the `init` block. Also you need to add semicolor after last enum item to add any new functions or overrides.

```
enum class GuideType(var type: String) {
    DEF_TYPE("default");

    override fun toString(): String {
        return type // working!
    }
}
```

Comment: Possibly the first time in the 2+ years I've been using Kotlin that I intentionally used a semicolon. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: No need to override `toString` in this case, after setting type to val/var.
You can access it by `GuideType.DEF_TYPE.getType()`

Comment: Is it possible to make the toString() function to a subclass? So that no need to provide the toString() for every enum like it.

Comment: Maybe use `private val type:String` instead of `var type:String` as you most likely don't want to ever alter the stated `type`. @IshaanKumar `toString` is needed for string interpolation however.

Answer (score 1):

In primary constructors, you need to use `var` or `val` if you want it to be globally visible (which includes locally in class/enum methods). Otherwise it's just locally in the initialization. Consider this:

```
public GuideType (String type) {}
```

Compared to this:

```
private String type;
public GuideType (String type) { this.type = type; }
// Getters and setters
```

Without `var` or `val`, it'll produce something roughly equivalent to the first one<sub>1</sub>. You can also access it in the `init` block, and in class-level variable initialization. So, in order to use it in a method, prepend val:

```
enum class GuideType(val type: String) { ... }
```

Since the variable (probably) won't be changed, it should be a `val`. You can, of course, use `var` too.

---

Note that this applies to primary constructors. Secondary constructors work differently.

---

<sub>1: Kotlin will also produce a bunch of null-safety stuff including @NotNull and null checks, but the code is still the rough equivalent</sub>

Answer (score 0):

You ca extend the Enum class with a method as this:

```
fun <K> Enum.Companion.toString(string: K): String {
    return string.toString()}


Enum.toString(DEF_TYPE("default")) // 'defaut'
```